# Nunit fails to start my application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit-2.5, white-framework

Visual Studio 2010 Express C#, NUnit 2.5.8, White 0.2.0

I am trying to write some tests with the NUnit + White framework.
I can get the White demo (ListBoxExample) up and running without problems.

But when I write a simple test for my own application (.Net 4.0), I have 2 problems:

1. Application.Launch(""):
   This statement does not complain, but does NOT launch my application at all. The path is correct because if I put an incorrect path, I get an error. With the right path there are no errors, but no application is starting.
2. application.GetWindow(...)
   This statement causes an error:

> *DocBackupTestSuite.Tests.StartupTest: System.IO.FileLoadException : Could
>   not load file or assembly 'Bricks,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's
>   manifest definition does not match the
>   assembly reference. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131040)*

But the Bricks.dll file IS referenced in my project...

Thank you for your help

Davy

Comment: omg it's so annoying i hear for you since i have the same problem as well

Answer (score 0):

First problem is solved.

The code did not wait long enough to leave time for the application to start.
Added a Thread.Sleep(10000) after the Application.Launch() statement, and now it starts up.

2nd problem is still pending...
Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

2nd problem also solved:

A reference to *Bricks.RuntimeFramework* was missing.
After adding this, my test runs fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you face this problem below when you use the UI automation library(White-project)

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Bricks, 
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=83a26c96fb92c77f' or one of its dependencies.   
The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Bricks, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=83a26c96fb92c77f'
```

please take the following solution:

Add Reference of the dll list as follow:

•Bricks

•Bricks.RuntimeFramework

•Castle.Core

•Castle.DynamicProxy2

•log4net

•nunit.framework

•White.NUnit

•Xstream.Core

Hope your code can be work successfully now.

Download theses stuff here

http://white-project.googlecode.com/svn/tags/0.20/lib/

Reference fromhttp://sunshinetoast.com/Default.aspx